# return values of case calss and why this happens in scala?

Tags: scala

I am a freshman to Scala, and tring to to study rocket source code (develped by Scala/Chisel), and I don't understand the below case class source code segment. My question is when we refer reg_cycle, what's the return the value (value ? )? And could you do some introductions why this happens in Scala ?

```
//source code for how to use case calss
  val reg_instret = WideCounter(64, io.retire)
  val reg_cycle = if (enableCommitLog) reg_instret else WideCounter(64)

  if (xLen == 32) {
      read_mapping += CSRs.mcycleh -> (**reg_cycle** >> 32)
      read_mapping += CSRs.minstreth -> (reg_instret >> 32)
      if (usingUser) {
        read_mapping += CSRs.cycleh -> (reg_cycle >> 32)
        read_mapping += CSRs.instreth -> (reg_instret >> 32)
      }
    }

//source code for case calss
case class WideCounter(width: Int, inc: UInt = UInt(1), reset: Boolean = true)
{
  private val isWide = width > 2*inc.getWidth
  private val smallWidth = if (isWide) inc.getWidth max log2Up(width) else width
  private val small = if (reset) Reg(init=UInt(0, smallWidth)) else Reg(UInt(width = smallWidth))
  private val nextSmall = small +& inc
  small := nextSmall

  private val large = if (isWide) {
    val r = if (reset) Reg(init=UInt(0, width - smallWidth)) else Reg(UInt(width = width - smallWidth))
    when (nextSmall(smallWidth)) { r := r + UInt(1) }
    r
  } else null  

  val value = if (isWide) Cat(large, small) else small
  lazy val carryOut = {
    val lo = (small ^ nextSmall) >> 1
    if (!isWide) lo else {
      val hi = Mux(nextSmall(smallWidth), large ^ (large +& UInt(1)), UInt(0)) >> 1
      Cat(hi, lo)
    }
  }

  def := (x: UInt) = {
    small := x
    if (isWide) large := x >> smallWidth
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to make sense of "when we refer reg_cycle, what's the return the value (value ? )?" — what are you asking?

Comment: I mean in the operation "(reg_cycle >> 32)", what's value we we will get.

Comment: are you asking what `>> 32` means?

Comment: It's not true, reg_cycle is generated from reg_instret, reg_instret is generated from case class WideCounter. I want to know when we do "reg_cycle >> 32", which will be return from WideCounter and why this happens ? Thanks again!

Comment: could you show us your imports? or WideCounter object companion if it is defined.

Comment: read_mapping += CSRs.mcycleh -> (**reg_cycle** >> 32) if you are asking what >> does, it's the right shift operator. so the value ov reg_cycle >> 32 depends on the value of reg_cycle. suppose value of reg_cycle = 1245698731452887451L then return valure of 5 >> 32 will be 290036837

Answer (score 1):

reg_cycle is a WideCounter. It's initialized to different specific instances depending on the value of the logging boolean.

WideCounter has several fields, which can be accessed by their names, width, inc, and reset.

Comment: But `WideCounter` doesn't _appear_ to have a `>>` method.  It looks like the posted code is incomplete.

Comment: The code is completed (it's from open source Rocket/RISC-V project). I guess field "value" (val value = if (isWide) Cat(large, small) else small) defiened in case calsss is returned when we do operation "reg_cycle >> 32". But why this happens ? Which mechanism in Scala is used ?

Comment: Hi Kevin, my quetion is in operation "reg_cycle >> 32" or "reg_instret >> 32", which method in case calss WideCounter is used. Thanks!

Comment: @Bibo; The posted code is **not** complete.  It can't be compiled as is. It you prefer not to post a complete and compilable example then post a link to the complete source.

Comment: you are right, I found below source code in rocket project:   implicit def wcToUInt(c: WideCounter): UInt = c.value; this method should be the key reason.